# Spring Boot Many To Many duplicate records

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I m trying to create User Management API Using Spring Boot. (Code First)

**I have problem while adding new User.**
for example if i'm add   **root_1  - admin and root_2 - admin**   in **Role** table i have two record

Role Table:

```
[id]  [name]
 1    admin
 2    admin
```

[image]

Model: 
**User**

```
@Data
@Entity
public class AppUser {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    //@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

    public AppUser() {
    }

    public AppUser(String username, String password, String firstName, String lastName, Set<Role> roles) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

}
```

**Role** :

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

Service **UserServiceImpl**:

```
    @Override
    public void addUser(AppUser user) {

        user.setPassword(encoder.encode(user.getPassword()));

        userRepository.save(user); // JpaRepository
    }
```